# GWT2.0.3 and JDK1.6.0_21 does not work

Tags: gwt, intellij-idea, java-6

Just to inform GWT developers, GWT 2.0.3 and 2.0.4 does not work in Intellij with JDK 1.6.0_20.

Why is this? No error, no nothing, just no output of gwt in war.

Me thinks Oracle has done something bad again.

Comment: The title is misleading (title is GWT+JDK while content says GWT+Intellij+JDK). Comment abount Oracle is offline.

Comment: If you made sure this is not a problem on your end, you should file a bug report at http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are there any errors in USER_HOME/.IntelliJIdea90/system/log/idea.log file?